# XSLT 1.0: Howto merge XML nodes, then move attribute to child and change their values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML (omitted some other nodes, children and attributes for clarity):

```
<Restriktion Typ="Aussageeinheit">
    <Restriktion Code="49" moreAttributes><moreChildren/></Restriktion>
    <Restriktion Code="10"/>
</Restriktion>
<Restriktion Typ="Plot">
    <Restriktion Code="78"/>
</Restriktion>
<Restriktion Typ="Baum">
    <Restriktion Code="22"/>
</Restriktion>
```

I would like to transform it with XSLT 1.0 into:

```
<Restriktionen>
    <Restriktion Code="49" Typ="1" MoreAttributes><MoreChildren/></Restriktion>
    <Restriktion Code="10" Typ="1"/>
    <Restriktion Code="78" Typ="2"/>
    <Restriktion Code="22" Typ="3"/>
</Restriktionen>
```

e.g. merge parent element Restriktion into Restriktionen, move the attribute Type to the children and change the attribute values from "Aussageeinheit" to 1, from "Plot" to 2 and from "Baum" to 3.

Comment: I'm afraid you have omitted too much. Could you show the parent node of `Restriktion`, please? And are there any other children beside `Restriktion`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this should work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::Restriktion)]"/>
        <Restriktionen>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Restriktion/Restriktion"/>
        </Restriktionen>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Restriktion">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="Typ">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../@Typ='Aussageeinheit'">1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../@Typ='Plot'">2</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../@Typ='Baum'">3</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where `parent` is the parent element of `Restriktion` (not shown in your example).

---

### Added:

> If the order of the children of `<parent>` matters, then there is the
>   problem that all children are placed before the child
>   `<Restriktionen>`. Is there a way to keep the order of the children ?

There are several ways to maintain the original order.

The best way is to name the other child nodes explicitly in `xsl:apply-templates` instructions before and after `<Restriktionen>`.

Alternatively, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Restriktion[1]">
    <Restriktionen>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../Restriktion/Restriktion" mode="grp"/>
    </Restriktionen>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Restriktion"/>

<xsl:template match="Restriktion" mode="grp">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="Typ">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../@Typ='Aussageeinheit'">1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../@Typ='Plot'">2</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../@Typ='Baum'">3</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that any child nodes interspersed in-between `Restriktion` elements will be placed after the `<Restriktionen>` block (although you can control that by selecting another predicate instead of `[1]`).

If no such child nodes can exist, you could also do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Restriktion[1]/preceding-sibling::*"/>
        <Restriktionen>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Restriktion/Restriktion"/>
        </Restriktionen>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Restriktion[last()]/following-sibling::*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Restriktion">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="Typ">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../@Typ='Aussageeinheit'">1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../@Typ='Plot'">2</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../@Typ='Baum'">3</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, exactly what I needed.

Comment: If the order of the children of <parent> matters, then there is the problem that all children are placed before the child <Restriktionen>. Is there a way to keep the order of the children ?

Comment: Do you know the names of these children?

Comment: Yeah I do, but I was just wondering if there was a way of not having to specify them explicitly. If not, no problem.

Comment: @Simon Specifying them explicitly is the best way. See the addition to my answer for some alternatives.